# MySQL with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, remote-access, google-cloud-sql

I am a Visual Basic.net developer and am wanting to have an online MySQL database to store some application attributes.

Does Google Cloud SQL support remote access from applications? Is this an easy service to use and am I correct in saying that the price is $0.10 per Million accesses to the MySQl database?

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: http://googleappengine.blogspot.in/2011/12/simple-development-of-app-engine-apps.html

Comment: Automatically add the JDBC driver to the classpath and set VM arguments required to connect to a local MySQL database and/or a remote Google Cloud SQL database.

Comment: If I wish to connect to a MySQL database, is it simple enough to just specify the hostname, username, password and database? Or is it more complicated with Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some free mysql databases  for example db4free.net  . U can use odbc namespace to connect to ur remote database. It is as easy as using MS SQL db with vb.net

```
       Dim cn As OdbcConnection

       cn = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MySQLServer;UID=sa;" & _
                         "PWD=mypassword;DATABASE=exampledb;")
```